# Django query doesn't return the instance that I just saved in database

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm working on a project that requires to trace the events related to a process. In my case I have `Registration` and `RegistrationEvent` models with the latter connected throug a ForeignKey to `Registration`.

I also have written a method of `RegistrationEvent` called `_ensure_correct_flow_of_events` which prevents from adding Events in an order that doesn't make sense and is called when `model.save` is called. Infact the flow of events must be `SIGNED -> STARTED -> SUCCESS -> CERTIFICATE_ISSUED`. At any moment the event `CANCELED` can happen.
In order to evaluate event sequence this method calls another method `_get_previous_event` which return the last event registered to `Registration`.

After a `SUCCESS` event is created, the `save` method calls `Registration.threaded_issue_certificate` which is a method that should create a certifcate and after that create a `CERTIFICATE_ISSUED` event in a new thread, in order to process the response fastly. Problem is when `CERTIFICATE_ISSUED` is about to be created `_ensure_correct_flow_of_events` and `_get_previous_event` are called and at this point `_get_previous_event` does not return the just created `SUCCESS` event but the previous `STARTED` event.

My log is

```
Checking correct flow, previous event: Course started - admin registration id: 1 current event_type: 3
Checking correct flow, previous event: Course started - admin registration id: 1 current event_type: 4
Exception in thread Thread-2 (threaded_issue_certificate):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/zenodallavalle/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Users/zenodallavalle/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
[21/Mar/2024 15:16:41] "POST /admin/main/registrationevent/add/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/zenodallavalle/Downloads/test/main/models.py", line 79, in threaded_issue_certificate
    return self.issue_certificate()
  File "/Users/zenodallavalle/Downloads/test/main/models.py", line 84, in issue_certificate
    RegistrationEvent.objects.create(
  File "/Users/zenodallavalle/Downloads/test/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 87, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/zenodallavalle/Downloads/test/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 679, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/Users/zenodallavalle/Downloads/test/main/models.py", line 175, in save
    self._ensure_correct_flow_of_events(is_new=is_new)
  File "/Users/zenodallavalle/Downloads/test/main/models.py", line 155, in _ensure_correct_flow_of_events
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: After started next event must be 'success' or 'canceled'
```

Why is that?

I leave my `models.py` here in order to replicate the behaviour.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from logging import getLogger

from main.utils import make_thread

logger = getLogger(__name__)
import threading


def make_thread(fn):
    def _make_thread(*args, **kwargs):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        thread.start()
        return thread

    return _make_thread


class Registration(models.Model):
    course_user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="registrations",
    )

    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def _check_user_not_signed_for_other_courses(self):
        other_registrations = self.course_user.registrations.exclude(pk=self.pk)
        if any([not r.ended for r in other_registrations]):
            raise ValueError("User already signed for another course")

    def _ensure_created_by_is_not_null(self):
        if self.created_by is None:
            raise ValueError("Created by is null")

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        is_new = self._state.adding
        if is_new:
            self._ensure_created_by_is_not_null()
            self._check_user_not_signed_for_other_courses()
        ret = super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        if is_new:
            RegistrationEvent.objects.create(
                course_registration=self,
                event_type=RegistrationEvent.EventType.SIGNED,
            )
        return ret

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.course_user} registration id: {self.pk}"

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Registration: {self.course_user} registration id: {self.pk}>"

    @property
    def ended(self):
        return self.events.filter(
            event_type__in=(
                RegistrationEvent.EventType.CERTIFICATE_ISSUED,
                RegistrationEvent.EventType.CANCELED,
                RegistrationEvent.EventType.FAILED,
            )
        ).exists()

    @property
    def last_event(self):
        return self.events.order_by("-created_at").first()

    @make_thread
    def threaded_issue_certificate(self):
        return self.issue_certificate()

    def issue_certificate(self):
        # Do something here
        # Register it as an event
        RegistrationEvent.objects.create(
            course_registration=self,
            event_type=RegistrationEvent.EventType.CERTIFICATE_ISSUED,
        )


class RegistrationEvent(models.Model):
    class EventType(models.IntegerChoices):
        SIGNED = 1, "Signed up"
        STARTED = 2, "Course started"
        SUCCESS = 3, "Course success"
        CERTIFICATE_ISSUED = 4, "Certificate issued"
        CANCELED = 5, "Cancelled"
        FAILED = 6, "Course failed"

    course_registration = models.ForeignKey(
        Registration,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="events",
    )
    event_type = models.IntegerField(choices=EventType.choices)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Creato il")
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Aggiornato il")

    @property
    def event_type_description(self):
        return self.EventType(self.event_type).label

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.event_type_description} - {self.course_registration}"

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<RegistrationEvent: {self.event_type_description} - {self.course_registration}>"

    def _get_previous_event(self, is_new):
        qs = self.course_registration.events.all()
        if not is_new:
            qs = qs.exclude(created_at__gte=self.created_at)
        return qs.order_by("-created_at").first()

    def _ensure_correct_flow_of_events(self, is_new):
        # If the course is completed (certificate issued or cancelled), no more events can be added
        if is_new:
            if self.course_registration.ended:
                raise ValueError(
                    "Il corso è completato, non è possibile aggiungere eventi"
                )

        if self.event_type == self.EventType.CANCELED:
            return  # No further checks needed

        previous_event = self._get_previous_event(is_new=is_new)
        print(
            "Checking correct flow, previous event:",
            previous_event,
            "current event_type:",
            self.event_type,
        )

        if not previous_event:
            if self.event_type != self.EventType.SIGNED:
                raise ValueError("First event must be 'signed'")
        elif previous_event.event_type == self.EventType.SIGNED:
            if self.event_type != self.EventType.STARTED:
                raise ValueError("After signed next event must be 'started'")
        elif previous_event.event_type == self.EventType.STARTED:
            if self.event_type not in (
                self.EventType.SUCCESS,
                self.EventType.CANCELED,
            ):
                raise ValueError(
                    "After started next event must be 'success' or 'canceled'"
                )
        elif previous_event.event_type == self.EventType.SUCCESS:
            if self.event_type != self.EventType.CERTIFICATE_ISSUED:
                raise ValueError(
                    "After success next event must be 'certificate issued'"
                )

    def _issue_certificate_if_needed(self, is_new):
        if not is_new:
            return
        if not self.event_type == self.EventType.SUCCESS:
            return
        self.course_registration.threaded_issue_certificate()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        is_new = self._state.adding

        if is_new:
            self._ensure_correct_flow_of_events(is_new=is_new)

        ret = super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        self._issue_certificate_if_needed(is_new=is_new)
        return ret
```

Comment: Did you try `event.refresh_from_db()` between the steps of the event flow?

Comment: What is the database backend you are using when executing these tests? If you remove `qs.exclude(created_at__gte=self.created_at)` does it work as expected?

Comment: @Ben as the event is new, refresh from database would raise an error, as it doesn't exist in database.

Comment: @sytech The database I'm using is sqlite3. Removing that line doesn't change the behaviour, as the line is executed only if the instance is edited (is_new==False) which is not the case

Comment: Also consider that the bug doesn't always happen, so I struggle even more to understand what can cause/prevent it. My suspicion is that it's something related to caching mechanisms

Comment: It is odd, especially if it's inconsistent. Since you don't even launch the thread until _after_ calling `super().save`, the ordering of events _should_ be OK... by the time `save` returns, the record _should_ exist. The only things I can posit right now might be (1) because of transaction behavior, if you are using a transaction explicitly or the `ATOMIC_REQUESTS` setting is `True`, or (2) your database isn't [storing fractional seconds](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/databases/#fractional-seconds-support-for-time-and-datetime-fields) for datetime objects (though I doubt this).

Comment: Though I don't have any specific details to articulate exactly what might go wrong, trying to do database operations in a separate thread is known to cause issues (though it's not immediately obvious to me how that might apply in this particular situation). There may be thread-local flags that get lost in your new thread or the two threads may somehow interfere with one another. If you do this synchronously instead of in a thread, I wonder if that problem goes away.

Comment: For whatever it's worth... when I try to reproduce this, I get an error anytime the background thread even tries to query the database. I use `TransactionTestCase` to prevent that problem. If I use an in-memory SQLLite table, I will intermittently get `sqlite3.OperationalError: database table is locked: ` so the test case will sometimes fail. Using a physical file seems to make it slow enough that this doesn't happen. The thread will sometimes fail to find the previous record _unless_ I wrap the first record creation in an `transaction.atomic` block and only launch the thread after the block.

Comment: cant you use just celery for django which will much simpler

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be a common issue with Django and how it handles multi-threaded operations and their timings. Specifically in this instance the issue is arising when a new thread is started for the CERTIFICATE_ISSUED event, before the SUCCESS event has fully updated the database. There are some solutions that Django offers, and the one I found best is to use post_save and receiver to automatically issue certificates in the instance that the event being processed is the SUCCESS event.

The imports needed would be:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
```

The method to implement would look something like:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=RegistrationEvent)
def issue_certificate_if_success(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
     if created and instance.event_type == RegistrationEvent.EventType.SUCCESS:
         instance.course_registration.threaded_issue_certificate()
```

There are other ways to do it if you don't want to adopt this approach. I've seen solutions using the transaction module as well.